# Expand df with range of dates to one row per day

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, date-range

I have a df that contains one line per item with a range of dates, and I need to expand it to contain one row per day per item.

It looks like this:

```
  from       to         id
1 25/02/2019 27/02/2019 A
2 15/07/2019 16/07/2019 B
```

And I want this:

```
  date       id
1 25/02/2019 A
2 26/07/2019 A
3 27/07/2019 A
4 15/07/2019 B
5 16/07/2019 B
```

I managed to write a code that works but it takes over one hour to run, so I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it.

My code:

```
df_dates = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(df)):

    start = df.loc[i]['from']
    end = df.loc[i]['to'] + np.timedelta64(1,'D') #includes last day of the range
    dates = np.arange(start, end, dtype='datetime64[D]')

    temp = pd.DataFrame()
    temp = temp.append([df.loc[i]]*len(dates), ignore_index=True)
    temp['datadate'] = dates

    df_dates = df_dates.append(temp, ignore_index=True)
```

It takes long because the real ranges are of about 50 years with over 1700 items so the new df is massive, but maybe you know a trick to do the same faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['from'] = pd.to_datetime(df['from'])
df['to'] = pd.to_datetime(df['to'])
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(row['from'], row['to'], freq='D'), 'id': row['id']})
           for i, row in df.iterrows()], ignore_index=True)
        date id
0 2019-02-25  A
1 2019-02-26  A
2 2019-02-27  A
3 2019-07-15  B
4 2019-07-16  B
```

Comment: what is the function of ```i``` in the loop? I know it doesn't work without it, but I can't figure out what it actually does as it is nowhere else in the code

Comment: `iterrows()` returns the index and value of the rows and `i` is the index in this case. you can replace it with `_`

Comment: What if we have multiple other attributes like id? Then how do we scale it? @luigigi

Answer (score 2):

You can first convert columns with dates [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html).  Then use [`itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) and [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for creating new expanding `DataFrame`:

```
df['from1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['from'])
df['to1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['to'])

L = [pd.Series(r.id, pd.date_range(r.from1, r.to1)) for r in df.itertuples()]
df1 = pd.concat(L).reset_index()
df1.columns = ['date','id']
print (df1)
        date id
0 2019-02-25  A
1 2019-02-26  A
2 2019-02-27  A
3 2019-07-15  B
4 2019-07-16  B
```

Comment: What if we have multiple other attributes as id? @jezrael